# Cannot execute /sbin/false while installing Solr 5.3.1

Tags: 14.04, solr

I had Solr 4.9.1 installed and I wanted to install the current version 5.3.1, which using **Solr** as a service, while 4.x version was using **jetty**.
I tried to uninstall it the normal way

```
sudo apt-get purge jetty
Package 'jetty' is not installed, so not removed
```

while `find / -name jetty` getting a list of folders and files, so I had to remove the following files manually

```
/var/solr
/opt/solr-4.9.1
/opt/solr
/etc/init.d/solr
/etc/default/jetty
/etc/init.d/jetty
```

Using apache [guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production) to install Solr 5.3.1, I am getting `Cannot execute /sbin/false` error at the end of installation and also if I try to get it start `service solr start`.

Do I have to add any environment variables? if not (as the guide mentioned), what am I suppose to do?

Comment: AFAIK `false` is usually in `/bin` not `/sbin`: perhaps it's a problem with the install script?

Answer (score 1):

You may try creating a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /bin/false /sbin/false
```

At least it solve my similar issue.

Comment: No, but removing and recreating the solr user did.